# maximum accepted value for fig.width knitr option

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

What is the maximum accepted value for `fig.width`? Looks like it is not effective to pass a value more than 12. I have been testing with different values for figure height and width for HTML output. I have ensured that the width value is not less than height always.

Comment: Are you writing to PDF? What is the paper size you are targeting?

Comment: Note that it must not be smaller than ```fig.height``` : https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/0dec03b44ba59d9d7a47459a1977c2349937d2e9/R/hooks.R

Comment: @RichardSprague that's just an example of how you *could* write your own hook to manipulate options, e.g., enforce `fig.height <= fig.width`. The actual hook (the uncommented code) does not have that restriction.

Comment: @MrFlick I am writing to an HTML page with default page options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**knitr** does not impose any limits on `fig.width`. You can set it to any value allowed by the graphical device you use (for HTML output, the default device is `png()`).

The reason that you don't see a wider figure is due to the default CSS styles in HTML output: the maximum width of images [has been set to `100%`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/d31ec87679571a84092b5bec4f7de6f42511e9a4/inst/rmd/h/default.html#L134), i.e. images cannot be wider than the page.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wishing to change this configuration from Rmarkdown you can include the following in your code (150% is just an example):

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
img {
  max-width:150%;
  height: auto;
}
```
````

For more details read the excellent documentation https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html